# Can I always use ++ or -- as a shorthand for parseFloat?

Tags: javascript

`!!` always works fine for converting *String*, `undefined`, *Object* and *Number* types to *Boolean* type in JavaScript:

```
!!0           // false
!!1           // true
!!10          // true
!!""          // true
!!"any"       // true
!!undefined   // false
!!null        // false
!!NaN         // false
!!{}          // true
```

It seems using `!!` is totally safe. I've seen people using this for converting variables.

But I'm not sure about `++` or `--` for converting *String* types to *Number* types. In these examples it looks using `++` for converting is safe:

```
var ten = "10";
ten++  // 10

var nineHalf = "9.5";
nineHalf++ // 9.5

var n = "-10.06";
n++ // -10.06
```

Is there any case that `++`/`--` don't work as `parseFloat`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use a single `+` (unary plus operator). It is a common practice just like `!!` for booleans.

```
(+"10.06")
```

The `++` version makes me afraid of the increment operators doing evil tricks when I'm not looking.

---

Edit: And of course, the postIncrement operator doesn't even work on string literals.

```
"10.06"++  //syntax error
```

Comment: @Mohsen: Yes, but you still have the problem that ++ destroys the variable afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing is that it has the side effect of adding one to the original variable. The effect of

```
var n = "-10.06";
n++
```

for example, is the same as

```
var n = "-10.06";
Number(n)++
```

Basically, any math operator when applied to a string will first convert it to a number using the `Number` function.